# PHP Script to Retrieve RSS Feed, timeout issue

Tags: php, xml

I am running a PHP script which calls out to world weather online to retrieve wave height, wave duration and water temperature by latitude longitude. However my host only allows 10 second script execution. I was wondering if I could trouble the community to give me some ideas / pointers on optimizing my script, as I do not have access to the php_ini on my host. The script works, only updates around 35 records. There are 100 records total. Me thinks I am throwing to much data at the world weather API.

Here is my script:

```
$connection=mysql_connect('myhost', 'user', 'post');
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}


$db_selected = mysql_select_db('ilovebigbutts', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Here I am selecting the lat long and pri_id from table
$query = "SELECT * FROM beaches";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row["pri_id"];
$lat = $row["lat"];
$lng = $row["lng"];

$feed_url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/marine.ashx?  key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&q=".$lat.",".$lng."&format=xml";
$xmlString = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString); 
$items = $xml->xpath('weather/hourly');
$closeItems = array(); 
$new_array = array(); 
foreach($items as &$item)  
{ 
$waves = $item->swellHeight_m;
$wave_secs = $item->swellPeriod_secs;
$water_temp = $item->waterTemp_F;
$query1 = "UPDATE beaches SET waves = '$waves', wave_secs = '$wave_secs', water_temp = '$water_temp' WHERE pri_id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
  $update_result = mysql_query($query1);
  if (!$update_result) {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Get a real hoster. 10 secs execution time while you need to deal with network services over HTTP. Just get a real hoster. Take one with cron support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised this is taking > 10 seconds. Do you have an index on pri_id ? If you do, you could always put a limit on your original select query and do it in chunks.

Comment: I think you'll have to break the query up. It takes me 91 milliseconds to get a response from their site, so 100 requests is 9.1 seconds which is close enough to your time limit. No amount of further optimising of the code is going to give you enough time if fetching the response from their api is too slow already. I had a quick look and it doesn't look like you can combine long/latitude searches but it was only a very quick look!

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate your assistance today, its always nice to have a fresh set of eyes on an issue!

Answer (score 0):

Before optimizing, did you check if

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60); // 1min execution
```

works ?

Comment: yes i did, I just did not include this, sorry it is:  set_time_limit(25);